# How to change the colour of part of an object in Inkscape?

Tags: color, inkscape, shapes

I'm attempting to change the colour of an SVG image. Here is a screenshot of the image set I'm working with.

[image]

Take for example the partly cloudy image (2nd line, 2nd from left). How can I change the colour of the sun only so that it is different to the colour of the cloud?

My attempt so far has been to open the image in Inkscape, press Shift+Ctrl+F to open Fill and Stroke. Then select the object and change the hex color. The problem is, both the sun and the cloud change colour.

Ref: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/meteocons/

Comment: then they are probably one single shape. You'll have to manually split them--vector objects can only have a single fill.

Comment: Can I find out if it's a single shape?

Comment: Yes, yes you can!

Comment: What Ryan's saying is that this is very basic knowledge of Inkscape. I'd advice you to seek out a beginner's tutorial for the software, or its help files, and try to find oud using that.

Comment: Thanks. It is in fact a single shape. You mention I'd have to manually split them; I'm guessing that will need more than basic knowledge. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Note that you have a solitary cloud and a solitary sun in your icon set. You can easily rebuild the sun-and-cloud icon from this and still have separate components you can separately colour.

Comment: Have you simply tried to use the [Bucket Fill](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Bucket-SimpleUse.html) tool?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I haven't tried. Do you think the outcome would look professional?

Comment: You can try it, it's very simple. The Bucket Fill tool creates in a delimited space a closed path with the selected color. Usually you need to upscale a little the generated path and send it to bottom. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, open that single icon (within the SVG folder in the zip you attached, it's called "8.svg"). After deleting that grid background, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> a few times to get it out of any groups it might be in.
[image: The icon after breaking the paths]
^ Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to break it into separate paths. Don't panic at the disfiguration of the icon! Simply deselect the part that is the sun and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to recombine the rest of it. Now the icon will be on top of the newly separated part, but you can use <kbd>End</kbd> or `Object > Lower to Bottom` to put the separated part on top.
[image: The separated part with the new fill color]
^ Then use the Fill and Stroke menu as you described to change the color of this one part individually.

And I did it to make this answer, so [here's a link](https://easyupload.io/l2f9xq) to my edited version so you don't have to do it :). (Make sure to download it in 30 days since it expires then.)